# Angular10 Dynamic/conditional import of module for one route

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-module

In our application, for a given route we want to load either moduleV1 or moduleV2 depending on some conditions (the module should be lazy-loaded).

We would like something like:

```
[{
  path: 'myservice',
  loadChildren: () => import(/* moduleV1 or moduleV2 */).then(mod => mod.Module),
}];
```

Until now, we tried puting the import in a guard for this route but:

1. Even if the module looks to be loaded, the navigation to the target route is not done
2. If we try to return an UrlTree from our guard, we are looping forever
3. Using a guard to do this looks like a Bad Practice...

What could be a clean approach for this functionality?

Comment: Perhaps this would help: https://medium.com/@german.quinteros/angular-use-the-same-route-path-for-different-modules-or-components-11db75cac455

Comment: What kind of conditions? Could you calculate them out ahead of time?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas No, it's runtime conditions (eg attributes of the current user). We are currently looking at the link from Akirus as the 2nd use case is looking like ours.